# Predicate equivalence from Horn clauses?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I have the following Horn clauses (=P):

```
even(n).
forall X (even(s(s(X))) <- even(X)).

even'(n).
forall X (even'(s(s(X)) <- even'(X)).
```

Can I prove one direction of equivalence:

```
P |- forall X (even(X) -> even'(X)).
```

Comment: Here `n` is some ground term, appearing in both clause sets?

Comment: n is a FOL constant. X is a FOL variable. even and even' are FOL predicates of arity 1. s is a FOL function of arity 1. There are no further definitions around that would involve n or s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot prove $\forall x.(\mathit{even}(x) \to \mathit{even}'(x))$, because it isn't necessarily true. Intuitively, although $\mathit{even}$ and $\mathit{even}'$ have suggestive names, your axioms do not necessarily specify the entire domain.  For instance, suppose that there is an $m$ such that $\mathit{even}(m) \land \lnot\mathit{even}'(m)$.  There's nothing in the axioms that would make this an inconsistent interpretation.  Then there is an interpretation where it is not the case that $\forall x.(\mathit{even}(x) \to \mathit{even}'(x))$ holds.

Comment: For example the two element model with `s(s(n)) = n`, and `even` true both for `n` and `s(n)` while `even'` is true only for `n`.

Comment: @hardmath That's a good example of a concrete countermodel.

Comment: @CookieMonster I don't see why $s(s(n)) \not = n$ is sufficient to produce a counterexample, although a counterexample could certainly have $s(s(n)) \not = n$.  Any countermodel just needs to have the interpretation of $\mathit{even}$ not be a subset of $\mathit{even}'$.

Comment: @CookieMonster Ah, sorry, I hadn't noticed the discrepancy between the question title (equivalence) and the question text (implication from even to even').  Yes, for (un)equivalence, the interpretations just need to be different.  For (non)implication, even just needs to not be a subset of even'.

Comment: I would say lfp <> Universe, i.e. a non-trivial least fixpoint is sufficient and also necessary. (Hope lfp is always defined as a concept, can we get it via set theory?)